# How to switch SVN server from one IP address to another

Tags: macos, svn

I recently move office and the IP address of my SVN server has changed so I can't access my SVN server. It's actually on my Mac but other people are accessing it at the moment. I am using SSH to access SVN before so the protocol I used is svn+ssh.

Supposed my current IP is [Current IP], my previous IP is [Previous IP]
I used the following command in the Terminal to relocate my SVN server but it gave me an error saying "." is not a working copy.

```
svn switch --relocate svn+ssh://[Previous IP]/usr/svn svn+ssh://[Current IP]/usr/svn
```

Which command should I use to relocate my SVN server so others can still access it?

Comment: `svn switch` is used to manage the upstream server for a specific working copy -- and your current working directory doesn't appear to be inside a current working copy. What specifically are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps `svn switch` is not the right tool.

Comment: I want to change the IP address so I can access the SVN server. It's using the old IP address now.

Comment: Are you trying to change the IP address in a specific working copy?

Comment: No I am changing the IP address of the SVN server, or repository? Because I need the IP address in the URL to be able to check out my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Subversion server tools do not care what your IP address is; since you're using `svn+ssh`, you only need to make sure that the SSH server is listening on the new IP address.

You can change your IP address via the *System Preferences* interface; select whichever interface you're configuring, change the IP address to whatever your new ISP has instructed you to use, and go from there. (It might be easier to reboot the computer than restart all the running services.)

Comment: But what will the new URL be? Suppose the old one is svn+ssh://192.168.0.2/usr/svn. I enter this in the SVN client or command line. But now the IP address of my computer where the SVN server is located has changed to 192.168.100.2. Needn't I change the IP address in the URL to access the repository?

Comment: You will need to change the IP address in the url _on your clients_, but that is the problem for the clients -- i.e., the working copies.